# Stack Exchange App for Windows 7

Tags: discussion, feature-request, app-request, windows

I was just wondering If anyone had made a Stack Exchange app for Windows 7 like can be accomplished in Chrome but without needing to have any software like Chrome installed. 
If such an app does not exist but people can give me some guidance on making one that would be great because I am new to coding.

Ham Radio SE in Chrome webapp:
[image: Ham Radio SE in Chrome webapp]

Comment: @BrockAdams It does not require that a browser be installed and because of this makes usage of it simpler. Hopefully it would also require next to no memory to run, compared to leaving a browser open.

Comment: @BrockAdams It It would also hopefully consist of only one `.exe` file which would make it easier to move from computer to computer on a flashdrive and have access to [se] with a single click.

Comment: Well then, put that in your question -- along with why this is needed versus just having [a lightweight browser](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2485269/web-apps/5-lesser-known-browsers--free--lightweight-and-low-maintenance.html) that can run, stand-alone, off a flash drive.